# What iPhone apps have I already purchased?

Tags: itunes, iphone

I've bought many iPhone apps by now, some free and some paid.
I've reinstalled my computer, and in the new installation, iTunes is completely blank. 
On first sync, iTunes downloads the apps that are currently installed on my iPhone. 
But what about all those apps that I have bought and aren't currently installed?

**Is there a way to re-download all my apps into iTunes? 
 Where can I see a listing of all the apps I've ever downloaded?**

(Update: Apparently **not all purchased content is restored** - some things are inexplicably missing. You won't be charged anew for downloading them again, but you also won't be told what it is that you're missing.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To re-download all your apps into iTunes.

1. First you need to authorize your iTunes. (Store > Authorize Computer)
2. Next, check for available downloads (Store > Check For Available Downloads)

iTunes will then check for what you have purchased before, and give you an option to re-download your purchased apps.

To see a listing of all the apps you have purchased or downloaded, do this :

1. Go to Store > View My Account
2. Login
3. Click on "Purchase History"

You should now see all the apps you have downloaded before.

Cheers.

Comment: Your answer concerns "purchased apps". Does this include free apps? (Purchased, for a price of zero...)

Comment: Yes it includes free apps. $0.00. :)

Comment: I don't think they make a distinction between them. They are purchased, only for free :)

Comment: A free app is also considered a purchased app in App Store - just that the price is $0.00.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't you received emails with receipts for all the apps you ever purchased? That's the way I know what I got; it also shows you all the free apps, not only the paid apps.

Comment: Yes I thought of that too, but that would mean a LOT of manual work - sort through all iTunes mails, search each app name again, and download it. There has to be a smarter way...

Comment: Scoopdreams' way is definitely better.

Comment: @alex : stop! You are making me blush!

Answer (score 2):

If you go on the iTunes Store, Click on your name (top right) --> Type in your password and click View Account. The 3rd option says "View Purchases" :) Hope that helps. Atleast you know what to download.

Answer (score 1):

It's too bad I didn't get here back when this question was posted.  If iTunes will not recognize that it needs to download your apps again, you can call Apple and explain that your iTunes crashed.  They will then manually put every app ever purchased in your download queue.

The only caveat here is that if you previously had any apps (not already on your device that can be moved back at sync) that are no longer available via the app store (i.e. Apple or the Dev pulled the app, or the Dev stopped paying to license it), then it's not able to be re-downloaded, ever (at least not a signed copy through iTunes anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but here is what worked for me.

Since everything synchronised before, and the apps, music, pictures, etc. are saved on your computer somewhere, you can restore those.

When you open your iTunes (recently re-installed or otherwise) and have your device connected, click "Add folder to library" under Files and click on your computer name. Select all folders (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) and click "Add folders". After that is done, synchronising your device will upload all your apps again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "Add to Wish List" option in iTunes. It's impossible to add already purchased apps.

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would be rather tedious, with the ten bajillion apps on the store. But a good way to check on a single app if there's the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the apps on you phone then the easiest way is to right click on your iPhone as it appears in iTunes and then click [transfer purchases](http://gigaom.com/apple/transfer-applications-from-iphone-to-itunes/).